# Redirection to requested page after login in joomla

Tags: php, redirect, joomla, joomla3.0

I am newly working on joomla. This question is seen number of times. But none of the solutions completly solved the problem.

The situation will be like this. There will be many pages on the joomla application.some pages can be seen by everyone.for same cases like buying a product or adding review to a product need the user to log in.

So the page takes the user to the login page . Now the issue is the usual login takes user to a home page but in the above case it should take the user to the page where he is redirected from.

Is there a way joomla could identify where the login page is requested from. There are php ways of doing itby using session variables. But i want to know is there any way in which joomla handles this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Joomla has it's own Stack Exchange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/), you might have better luck asking over there since you're question isn't that well suited for SO.

Comment: Same question has been posted at: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/16459/120

Comment: Possible solution at: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/16115/120